# How to cast fetch API response to a specific type in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript, fetch-api

I'm trying to cast the response of an API call into a specific type in my code (TypeScript). However, I didn't succeed to get the response casted to my type, but only Object.

I tried several ways, in particular what is described here: https://www.carlrippon.com/fetch-with-async-await-and-typescript/

Type:

```
export interface MyType{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

Fetch code:

```
export default class api {
  static async get<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(body => {
          resolve(body);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Caller:

```
const result = await api.get<MyType[]>(
      "my-url-here"
    );
```

I expect `result` to be of type `MyType[]`, but it is `Object[]`. (with all the fields)

Further, I tried to change the type of the `name` field to `number` (while always keeping the same response from API, i.e. name is some string non-convertible to number) and expected some type casting error, but there was none. `result` is still created with the same content and with the same type: 
`result: Array(3) [Object, Object, Object]`

It seems that there isn't any casting at all.

Can you please tell me where I'm wrong at, and show me what to do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When trying out your types in [the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), everything seems fine. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: TypeScript is only a compiler. It compiles to JavaScript, where types (other than the JS types: boolean, number, object, etc.) don't exist anymore. And there is no casting in TypeScript. All your code does is saying to the compiler: trust me, the objects returned by my API will look like this. At runtime, the objects are just POJOs, and no type checking is done at all.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet, that's clear for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> expected some type casting error, but there was none.

TypeScript doesn't *cast*. It *assert*s. It is a way for you to *focefully* tell the compiler what something will be at runtime. If it doesn't turn out to be that at runtime its on you.

## Fix

Options, either:

- change the backend response so it matches what you are asserting.
- change the assertion to match what the backend is returning.

## More

- [TypeScript Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion)